# PostSharp string.Normalize not working

Tags: postsharp

I have PostSharp 4.2 enabled on my project.

Also, I have a test project with some integration tests that need to use some classes from PostSharp. So I have PostSharp on my test project.

Issue:

```
var text = "usuário"; 
Assert.AreNotEqual(text.Length, text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Length);
```

This test works only if PostSharp build is disabled on my test project.

Comment: This seems like a very interesting bug in PostSharp. I will report it.

Comment: Did you confirm it? I didn't have time to make a small project just to test this isolated yet.

Even looking at the IL I couldn't find a clue about why the behaviour changed.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it. There is no problem in IL, must be hidden on binary level - more investigation is needed. This is going to be very, very interesting:). I will let you know, if there are any news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed in PostSharp 4.2.24.